# jackson CSV allowComments only work for multiple line message?

Tags: java, csv, jackson, comments, jackson-databind

Example 1 (fail) :

```java
final String line = "# 134";  
CsvMapper mapper = mapperForCsv(); 
String[] it = mapper.readerFor(String[].class) 
       .with(mapper.schema().withComments()).readValue(line);
```

Example 2 (success) :

```java
final String line = "# 134";
CsvMapper mapper = mapperForCsv();
MappingIterator<String[]> its = mapper.readerFor(String[].class) 
       .with(mapper.schema().withComments()).readValues(line);
```

After I checked the codes I find that the withComments only works with multiple line message. Is it a bug or expected?

Answer (score 1):

When you create `MappingIterator` object you actually do not deserialise anything yet. You need to iterate over all rows or use `its.readAll()` method to start deserialisation process.

When you use `readValue` method you expect exactly one object. If it is not available, exception is thrown to inform you it is not possible. It can not just return `null` because it would be a silent failure and could cause `NPE` later.

With `MappingIterator` it is a different scenario because you need to iterate over it and `API` allows you to check next element. So, it is clear that if there no elements we can just stop iterating.

So, in my opinion it is not a bug.